# How do I remove icons from desktop?

Tags: kubuntu, icons

OS: Kubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64 
Host: 90BG003JUS Lenovo H50-55 
Kernel: 5.19.0-43-generic 
Uptime: 1 hour, 33 mins 
Packages: 3036 (dpkg), 26 (flatpak), 23 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
WM: KWin 
Theme: [Plasma], NsCDE [GTK2], Adwaita-dark [GTK3] 
Icons: Sweet-Yellow [Plasma], NsCDE [GTK2], Sweet-Yellow [GTK3] 
Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
Terminal Font: Anonymous Pro 16 
CPU: AMD A10-7800 Radeon R7 4C+8G (4) @ 3.500GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti 
Memory: 2785MiB / 15948MiB (17%)

I have many icons on my desktop and wish to remove them. 
I didn't put them there and they are duplicates of my home directory.
[image: Part of my desktop showing unwanted icons]

Answer (score 2):

To make sure your desktop shows files stored in the `~/Desktop` folder again, you will need to correct your `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file. Make sure `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` points to your `~/Desktop` folder, so open `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` in a text editor and make sure the line for the specia Desktop folder reads

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

This file may have changed because at one time you may have deleted, then recreated the "Desktop" folder. When "Desktop" does not anymore exist, the variable is automatically reverted to point to your home directory.

While you are there, you may also check the other variable assignments:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Alternatively, instead of manually updating the file, you may recreate a default file from scratch by

- Deleting `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`
- Logging out then back in

Comment: While you are there, you may also check the other variable assignments: Me: I had to add variables to each one - they were all blank after $HOME/

Comment: If this answer resolved your question, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the question.

Answer (score -1):

In xubuntu, those desktop icons are coming from ~/Desktop directory. They are basically files in the desktop directory. You can remove them by deleting the files, or moving them to another folder.

Comment: Can you expand a bit? How does the OP resolve their problem?

Comment: What's displayed on the desktop is actually files in the directory ~/Desktop.  I'm not sure what you mean by  OP.  ~ is the command line way of referencing your home directory in the UNIX world.

Comment: my point is, I don’t think your answer deals with their question … OP is ‘original poster’. I know what ~ means - I just don’t think your answer has given a solution to the problem - it’s just said where those icons are from. The OP was asking how to remove those icons, not what they represent.

Comment: My two primary methods of getting rid of such icons are: 1) right click then select delete or 2) use the rm command on the item in the ~/Desktop directory.